# ¿Cómo leer datos individuales de archivo .csv en C++?

Tags: c++, excel, estructuras-de-datos, archivo, csv

Estoy usando CodeBlocks C++ y lo que intento hacer es, leer un archivo (.cvs) el cual consiste de un listado de estudiantes con 5 columnas de datos. De esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código me solicita datos nuevos para incorporar a la tabla y posteriormete me lee los datos que contiene:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<windows.h>

using namespace std;
struct miEstudiante
{
    int id;
    char nombre[20];
    char apellido[20];
    int edad;
    double promedio;
};

int main()
{
    miEstudiante persona;
    ofstream fichero;
    fichero.open("fichero.csv",ios::app);

    for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Ingrese id, nombre, apellido,edad y promedio por favor: \n";
        cin>>persona.id;
        cin.ignore();
        cin.getline(persona.nombre,20);
        cin.getline(persona.apellido,20);
        cin>>persona.edad;
        cin>>persona.promedio;

        fichero<<persona.id<<";"<<persona.nombre<<";"<<persona.apellido<<";"<<persona.edad<<";"<<persona.promedio<<"\n";
        system("cls");
    }
        fichero.close();


    ifstream lectura;
    lectura.open("fichero.csv",ios::in);
    while (lectura.good())
    {
        lectura>>persona.id>>persona.nombre>>persona.apellido>>persona.edad>>persona.promedio;
        cout<<"ID-"<<persona.id<<" ";
        cout<<"Nombre-"<<persona.nombre<<" ";
        cout<<"Apellido-"<<persona.apellido<<" ";
        cout<<"Edad-"<<persona.edad<<" ";
        cout<<"Promedio-"<<persona.promedio<<endl;
    }
    lectura.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Mi duda surge al momento de leer el archivo, me lee el primer dato de ID y el segundo dato de `cout<<"Nombre-"<<persona.nombre<<" ";`, lee todo el archivo hasta el final, incluyendo los punto y coma";". Quisiera saber de que manera se puede arreglar y en que estoy fallando. gracias.

Comment: Disculpa, pero tu pregunta ya a sido respodida **http://www.ehowenespanol.com/leer-archivo-csv-como_546610/** Saludos desde Peru Posdata: Se que debi ponerlo en comentarios pero como aun no tengo suficiente reputacion, te respondere aqui y ademas se nota que necesitas ayuda urgente.

Comment: Gracias por el link, mi lectura del archivo es correcta y lee todo el archivo, mi pregunta es como tomar independientemente cada dato(o cada linea). En el link se encuentra la funcion strtok y NULL se supone que es para eso, pero no la explican completamente, me podrias completar esa informacion, que no termino de comprender. Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problema.

> Mi duda surge al momento de leer el archivo, me lee el primer dato de ID y el segundo dato de `cout<<"Nombre-"<<persona.nombre<<" ";`, lee todo el archivo hasta el final, incluyendo los punto y coma";"

Este *problema* surge de la manera en como funcionan los streams en C++. El operador de extracción de stream (`>>`) actúa de manera diferente según se estén leyendo números o letras.

En el caso de leer valores numéricos se hará la lectura hasta encontrar el primer caracter no numérico de los datos; así que la instrucción `lectura>>persona.id` leerá tantos caracteres numéricos como pueda hasta dar con el primero no numérico, que resultará ser el punto y coma (`;`).

La instrucción posterior está leyendo sobre una variable de texto (`persona.nombre`), el separador para texto es el espacio ( ) pero al no haber ningún espacio en los datos restantes lee todo lo que queda hasta finalizar.

Cuando llega a las instrucciones adicionales (`persona.apellido >> persona.edad >> persona.promedio`) no queda nada más en el archivo por leer, así que quedan vacías.

#### Sugerencia.

Puedes usar la función [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) para leer datos del archivo, a esta función se le puede especificar el separador a usar:

```
ifstream lectura;
lectura.open("fichero.csv",ios::in);

for (std::string linea; std::getline(lectura, linea); )
{
    std::stringstream registro(linea);

    for (std::string dato; std::getline(registro, dato, ';'); )
    {
        std::cout << dato << '\t';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

El código anterior leerá dato a dato, línea a línea... tan sólo deberías emparejar cada lectura con su dato correspondiente:

```
struct miEstudiante
{
    int id;
    std::string nombre;
    std::string apellido;
    int edad;
    double promedio;
};

miEstudiante persona;
ifstream lectura;
lectura.open("fichero.csv",ios::in);

for (std::string linea; std::getline(lectura, linea); )
{
    std::stringstream registro(linea);
    std::string dato;

    for (int columna = 0; std::getline(registro, dato, ';'); ++columna)
    {
        switch (columna)
        {
            case 0; // ID
                persona.id = std::stoi(dato);
            break;
            case 1; // NOMBRE
                persona.nombre = dato;
            break;
            case 2; // APELLIDO
                persona.apellido = dato;
            break;
            case 3; // EDAD
                persona.edad = std::stoi(dato);
            break;
            case 4; // PROMEDIO
                persona.promedio = std::stod(dato);
            break;
    }
}
```

Date cuenta que he pasado los datos de `miEstudiante::nombre` y `miEstudiante::apellido` a tipo `std::string` en lugar de `char[20]`, es más flexible y seguro usar un objeto `std::string` que un arreglo de caracteres de tamaño fijo.

Comment: Me has ayudado mucho, gracias. Solo tengo una pregunta. Ahora no me acepta ingresar los datos de la estructura que se les indico como `std::string`, como ingreso esos datos en archivo?

Comment: @JoséT. edita tu pregunta para añadir la nueva duda (con un ejemplo de lo que falla) o crea una nueva pregunta al respecto.